# How bits of this register is set in u-boot

Tags: c, arm, linux-device-driver, armv7, u-boot

I am trying to figure out how "SRAM_CTL1_CFG" register's 4th and 5th bit is set using following statement in u-boot:

```
/* Map SRAM to EMAC */
   setbits_le32(&sram->ctrl1, 0x5 << 2);
```

http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=drivers/net/sunxi_emac.c;h=11cd0ea06888ba8e271b0c10376306df5291a3e2;hb=HEAD#l503

As per datasheet if bit 4:5 of this "SRAM_CTL1_CFG" become "01"
 SRAM would be mapped to EMAC peripheral.

http://linux-sunxi.org/SRAM_Controller_Register_Guide

Shouldn't this `setbits_le32(&sram->ctrl1, 0x5 << 2)` be `setbits_le32(&sram->ctrl1, 0x4 << 2)`?

Comment: If you set setbits_le32(&sram->ctrl1, 0x4 << 2), SRAM_CTL1_CFG [2] will be 0. You can write CFG what you want: `int32_t cfg = what you want` `setbits_le32(&sram->ctrl1, cfg)`

Comment: By the usual way of reading bitfields, bits 4:5 of 0b00010100 _are_ 0b01, and not setting bit 2 wouldn't change that either. I don't understand the question...

Comment: Basically, I don't understand how setbits_le32(&sram->ctrl1, 0x5 << 2); would set bit 4:5 of SRAM_CTL1_CFG register

Comment: It is setting bit 4 only. Bit 5 has to be cleared. `01 = EMAC` The other 1 is to set bit 2 SRAM_

Comment: ok but default value tells that both the bits are clear initially.

Comment: Yes, then what is your question? To set `EMAC` you must set the bit 4 only. Why is it using `0x5` instead of `0x4`? Maybe it needs to set `SRAM_` bit also.

Comment: My Question is, to set bit 4 we could simply write setbits_le32(&sram->ctrl1, 0x4 << 2)  instead of setbits_le32(&sram->ctrl1, 0x5 << 2). I am just looking a bit detailed operation behind setbits_le32(&sram->ctrl1, 0x5 << 2)?

Comment: There are 2 notes at the end of firs table: _For A20 SRAM_A3_A4_MAP set up for emac by default, so you should change it for make it usable_

Comment: Why you use shift? You can set this bits like `setbits_le32(&sram->ctrl1, 0x10)` or `0x14`

Comment: Ahh, I see now you mean to say in order to make emac usable we need to also set SRAM_ (2nd bit of SRAM_CTL1_CFG ), right? Its kind of confusing as its given ? against values 0 and 1.

Comment: You can write on paper all fields of SRAM_CTL1_CFG, set by pen all bits 1 or 0 how you want, and get 32bit val that you want and put it into `setbits_le32`

Comment: Yes, I meant that.  Yes, question marks on values are not clear at first look.

Comment: @fandyushin The problem here is not how to set a bit, but why a specific bit is set. The code is from u-boot sources.

Comment: @LPs you need datasheet on this chip :)

Comment: Also bear in mind that in the case of Allwinner, the "documentation" is almost entirely reverse-engineered _from_ the source code.

Comment: Ok Thanks but they should have mentioned this fact that setting up  SRAM_ is also required to get emac working instead of ?.Also in actual datasheet they even don't talk about this SRAM_ bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the answer is that yes, (0x5 << 2), which is 20 decimal is 010100 in binary and we set '4:5' to '01' which is EMAC as well as setting bit 2 to 1.  Setting bit 2 to 1 is currently a magic value that we're setting because it's being set (presumably, I didn't trace all of the history back) in the sources allwinner provides, without further explanation.  Setting this to (0x4 << 2) would only set the claimed registers but is likely to have some hidden breakage on other boards where the magic value is required too.

Comment: Thanks for providing the insight, it helped :)